# Onpaste is only triggered by keyboard paste

Tags: javascript, html, paste

I have this code:

```
<input type="text" id="point-setter-input" onkeyup="if (!isNaN(this.value)) {document.getElementById('point-setter-span').setAttribute('data-data', 'data=' + this.value)};" onpaste="if (!isNaN(this.value)) {document.getElementById('point-setter-span').setAttribute('data-data', 'data=' + this.value)};" value="0">
<span class="api command initialized" data-command-name="SetPoints" data-events="click" data-container="#popup-content" id="point-setter-span" data-data="data=3">Pontok Mentése</span>
```

Whenever the `value` of the `input` changes via `onkeyup`, `data-data` of the `span` is getting that value if it happens to be a number. However, `onpaste` will never run. If I paste via the keyboard, then `data-data` of the `span` will be successfully updated, but this happens only because of my `onkeyup`, that is, if I do not have that attribute, even pasting with keyboard will not run. Why is `onpaste` disfunctional in my case? I have checked this in Chrome and Firefox.

EDIT

It turns out that onpaste is executed, but value is not the pasted text. I think an ugly solution is needed here, involving `setTimeout`.

Comment: i try to output the events to a console like this: `<input type="text" id="point-setter-input" onkeyup="console.log('keyup')" onpaste="console.log('onpaste')" value="0">
 <span class="api command initialized" data-command-name="SetPoints" data-events="click" data-container="#popup-content" id="point-setter-span" data-data="data=3">Pontok Mentése</span>` and it work fine. the `onpaste` work even before the `onkeyup`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paste event fires before the `<input>`'s value is set, otherwise you couldn't prevent its default behavior (which is to set the `<input>`'s value).

So when you check `if(!isNaN(this.value))`, the new value contained in the paste event is still not set.

To workaround this, simply listen to the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event, which will get fired in any case.

```js
var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
inp.onpaste = function() {
  console.log('paste', this.value);
};
inp.oninput = function() {
  console.log('input', this.value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inp">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this using `setTimeout`, so the value was changed when I used it:

```
<input type="text" id="point-setter-input" onkeyup="setTimeout(() => {if (!isNaN(this.value.trim())) {document.getElementById('point-setter-span').setAttribute('data-data', 'data=' + this.value)};}, 4);" onpaste="setTimeout(() => {if (!isNaN(this.value.trim())) {document.getElementById('point-setter-span').setAttribute('data-data', 'data=' + this.value)};}, 4);" value="0">
```